# I am unable to pass my if condition in cypress

Tags: javascript, json, cypress

I am trying to validate two json file and if the file data is valid then log it as "success", if it is invalid log it as "fails". But my test case tend to show fail all the time even the value present in the file is correct. I checked the values in the file by introducing logs in each function.

I tried the above stuff but i receive "fail" all the time
If there could be a solution i would be happy, i am not sure what is wrong
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d8XJw.png)

**test.cy.js**

````
cy.get('.dataTable-custom').get('.w-40').eq(0).then((el) => {
                cy.writeFile('request-number.json',
                    {
                        request_number: el.text()
                    })
            })
            cy.readFile('request-number.json').then((request) => {
                expect(request).to.be.an('object')
                cy.log(request)
                cy.readFile('application-details.json').then((json) => {
                    expect(json).to.be.an('object')
                    cy.log(json)
                    if (request === json) {
                        cy.log("success")
                    }
                    else {
                        cy.log("fail")
                    }
                })
            })```
**request-number.json**
`{
  "request_number": "ARS/0099/2023"
}`
  
**application-details.json**
`{
  "request_number": "ARS/0099/2023"
}`
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Javascript you can't just simply compare two objects using "==" or "===" , you need to convert the object to a stringified version first and then compare.

```
...
if (JSON.stringify(request) === JSON.stringify(json)) {
    cy.log("success")
  }
  else {
    cy.log("fail")
 }
...
```

Reference: https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-compare-two-objects-in-javascript

Comment: I have tried the same, it worked for me. Thank you Ry-ry

Answer (score 4):

The variables `request` and `json` contain references to the objects not the objects themselves.

When you compare them with `===` you are comparing the references not the contents. In fact you are asking "are these the same object?".

Clearly they are not, since you read them from different sources.

The way to compare the *content* is with Cypress [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual)

> **_.isEqual(value, other)**
>
> Performs a deep comparison between two values to determine if they are equivalent
>
> **Note:** This method supports comparing arrays, array buffers, booleans, date objects, error objects, maps, numbers, Object objects, regexes, sets, strings, symbols, and typed arrays

```js
if (Cypress._.isEqual(request, json)) {
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

why not use just deep equal?

```
expect(json).to.deep.equal(request)
```